# Firefox 17.0 Addon compatibility issue coming, created with cfx addon-sdk-1.17

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created one addon with cfx for firefox 17.0. But when I am running "cfx run", compatibilty issue is showing(i.e. the addon is not compatible with that firefox version). 
I have tried with .xpi (i.e. after running "cfx xpi" and then adding the xpi to firefox) file also but got same result. 
I cannot upgrade the version of the firefox.

Any kind of help is appreciable. 
This is my main.js code :

```js
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("https://www.mozilla.org/");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. Compatibility is a debugging issue.

Comment: I have added the sample code. If you have "cfx addon-sdk-1.17", run command "cfx init ". Then add this code to "lib\main.js" file. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. What is the actual error that is reported?  What does the browser console say?

Comment: Warning: WARN addons.xpi: Error loading bootstrap.js for jid1-BjLbZVLzx5ludg@jetpack: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: resource:///modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///tmp/tmpv9HJXr.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-BjLbZVLzx5ludg@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js
Line: 316

Warning: WARN addons.xpi: Add-on jid1-BjLbZVLzx5ludg@jetpack is missing bootstrap method install
Source File: resource:///modules/XPIProvider.jsm
Line: 3727

Warning: WARN addons.xpi: Add-on jid1-BjLbZVLzx5ludg@jetpack is missing bootstrap method startup
Source File: resource:///modules/XPIProvider.jsm
Line: 3727

Comment: Sorry for being too late to reply. Can you please look into the warnings.

Comment: Error: Search service falling back to synchronous initialization at SRCH_SVC__ensureInitialized@resource:///components/nsSearchService.js:2498
resource:///components/nsSearchService.js:3462
AHU_loadDefaultSearchEngine@resource:///components/nsBrowserContentHandler.js:814
resource:///components/nsBrowserContentHandler.js:565
dch_handle  resource:///components/nsBrowserContentHandler.js:793

Source File: resource:///components/nsSearchService.js
Line: 2499

Answer (score 0):

`cfx` has been discontinued and is no longer accepted by the AMO reviewers. Switch to `jpm` please - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx_to_jpm

Comment: I have already mentioned that I cannot upgrade the version of `Firefox`. `jpm` is supported for `Firefox 38` and onwards. I have `Firefox 17` installed in my system. So it is not possible for me to switch to `jpm`.

Comment: @techxxx I'm not sure how to fix this :( cfx is outdated and I never was too involved with it Maybe someone else can help. Do you plan to submit this addon to addons.mozilla.org?

Comment: No, I am not going to submit this addon to addons.mozilla.org.